# WPF Control hosted in Windows Forms SplitContainer

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

I have WPF control placed on Windows Forms SplitContainer with ElementHost. When I dragged the splitter, I got unpleasant artifacts on place of my WPF control. How can I manage with that trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience hosting WPF controls in a ElementHost is never perfect and always produces some rendering issues.  There's some discussion on a few workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589948/how-to-avoid-visual-artifacts-when-hosting-wpf-user-controls-within-a-winforms-md) that might help.

Comment: Thank you. I've found an issue of my problem there. I've disabled hardware accelaration of WPF Control rendering. Code:`code`public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl

{

    public UserControl1()

    {

        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += delegate

        {

            var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);

            var hwndTarget = source.CompositionTarget as HwndTarget;

            if (hwndTarget != null)

            {

                hwndTarget.RenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;

            }

        };

    }

}`code`