# Rendering issue with WPF controls inside ElementHost

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, elementhost

I am having a WinForms control, inside that I have a `TableLayoutPanel` which holds multiple `ElementHosts` and each `ElementHost` contains a WPF control.

Everything works fine except when the size of controls is bigger then window and `ScrollBar` is there; when I scroll down, the controls get rendered distorted, like this -

[image]

On maximizing the window or re-sizing it, controls render properly
(reducing the size such that controls go out of visible area and then increase the size again to bring them back in visible area)

This doesn't happen with WinForms control in the same window just the WPF ones; any idea why this is happening and any solution for this?

Comment: Anyone, anything....let me know if any other detail can be of help in solving this issue!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589948/how-to-avoid-visual-artifacts-when-hosting-wpf-user-controls-within-a-winforms-m

Comment: Note that on Windows 7 this problem does not occur when using a "classic" Windows theme. It seems to happen only when using the "Aero" theme.

Comment: @DimitriC. Thanks for info, didn't noticed that in this case but yes I have come across some theme related issues in WPF/WinForms interoperability and they always reminds me of browser incompatibility issues and hacks used their :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
this.Loaded += delegate
{
    var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
    var hwndTarget = source.CompositionTarget as HwndTarget;

    if (hwndTarget != null)
    {
        hwndTarget.RenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
    }
};
```

Try using that in the wpf control you are hosting. This is a known rendering issue of the the wpf controls that are hosted in win forms. Changing the rendering mode to software only will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Valentin, Sounds interesting, will try this solution and hope it would work.

Comment: Some info regarding performance impact is mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2007/10/10/performance-improvements-in-wpf-in-net-3-5-3-0-sp1.aspx)

Comment: Works fine for me. I have splitters and several ElementHosts, the fragmenting and black parts do no longer show after applying this method.

Comment: This worked on my machine but caused some others to crash (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473857/what-causes-windows-to-hang-in-this-wpf-ribbon-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719627/wpf-elementhost-in-winforms-crashes-windows-when-maximized) I still couldn't find a better solution

Comment: Does this mean that we will lose performance while using software rendering and more rely on CPU?

Comment: I had a wpf control inside a winform elementhost that wouldn't draw on ONE of my dual screen setup (But worked fine on the other screen!?). This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved forcing a refresh of the `ElmenetHost` in the scroll event of the `TableLayoutPanel`

Comment: Thanks Mackho, will try this and see if it works. BTW did this had any impact on the performance?

Comment: No I didn't notice any significant decrease of performance, but I have to say my form is pretty light so i can't guarantee you anything ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is gonna sound like total B.S. but it worked for me: in the `Load` event of your form, resize the form.

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
   public MyForm()
   {
      Load += (o, e) => { Width -=1; Width +=1; };
   }
}
```

After the form has been resized, I could not force a display issue.

Comment: That sounds really interesting, I will try to test this and see if it works in my application.

Comment: I'd like to know why this got a downvote.  It actually solved the problem for me

Comment: Not sure when/who downvoted it, but its too old for anyone to remember. I also don't remember if I ever tried that or not, but upvoting it as its a potential solution for sure.

Comment: Actually, we still use this approach in some of our code. Worth to consider as an option.