# WPF UserControl doesnt render properly

Tags: wpf, vb.net, telerik, docking

I have a WPF user control that just contains a simple telerik grid. I embedded this user control into a Element host control and added the host control to a 3rd party docking library that provides Visual studio like docking functionality.

Now in my windows application all the docking works fine but when i enable the autohide for the docking container of the user control the user control is not rendered properly, it only renders when i move my pointer on the controls. 
Any suggestions on how to get rid of the issue? 
I tried updatelayout(),InvalidateVisual() none of them seems to be working. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: without code, not possible in your case.

Comment: Hi, I don't have the code for the third party docking library. And the user control is just a basic control with a telerik grid bound to datasource. I can send post the code of the control if needed.

Comment: what `Docking Framework`  do you use?

Comment: Thats a framework called Docking Manager developed by DotNetMagic which is no longer available now. The situation i mentioned doesnt arise if i use a simple window form and win form user control. It happens only when i use WPF user control. It seems that the WPF usercontrol doensn't repaint iteself when i click on AutoHide button. Any suggestions?

Comment: `this.Loaded += delegate
{
    var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
    var hwndTarget = source.CompositionTarget as HwndTarget;

    if (hwndTarget != null)
    {
        hwndTarget.RenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
    }
};`  got his from another stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859821/rendering-issue-with-wpf-controls-inside-elementhost this solved my issue.